# What is the best method for compiling a project with multiple directories in vscode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

The problem is simple. Say you have 3 files in a project and I want to compile them all.

## src/proj-runner/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  Greeting *hello = new Greeting();
  cout << hello->hello() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

## src/proj-class/class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

Greeting::Greeting() {
    
}

string Greeting::hello() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

## src/proj-class/class.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Greeting {
    public:
        Greeting();
        string hello();
};
```

How do I do it without typing g++ proj-runner/main.cpp proj-class/class.cpp every time? I'm using VSCode on linux.

Comment: use a BUILD TOOL, Make, CMake, ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vscode build task to run the command for you. To do that, create a `.vscode` directory in your workspace root and in that directory create a file called `tasks.json`. Add the following to that file:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build_main_and_class",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ proj-runner/main.cpp proj-class/class.cpp",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can just do any of the following:

- Command+Shift+B
- Command+Shift+P and select `Tasks: Run Build Task`
- Click Terminal > Run Build Task...

You can read more about tasks in the vscode docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_typescript-hello-world

Comment: Thanks! I saw the docs, but since it featured TypeScript I didn't think it was relevant to my situation.